# Cannot get custom fonts to work, even when copy pasting tutorial code

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web Font Sample</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
      src: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf");
    }

    body { font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  This is Bitstream Vera Serif Bold.
</body>
</html>
```

This bit of code is available on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face. It is supposed make the sentence "This is Bitstream Serif Bold" appear in the VeraSeBD font. However it simply does not.

I *can* change fonts to arial for example. Using this code, the font *is* different:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web Font Sample</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
      src: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf");
    }

    body { font-family: arial }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  This is Bitstream Vera Serif Bold.
</body>
</html>
```

How does one proceed when even copy pasting sample code still does not make it work?

The setup for the test is using a PHP server running on localhost on a windows machine

Comment: Probably a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue. If it works when you download the font file and use it locally, then it definitely has to do with CORS.

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser console refering `https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf` ?

Comment: I'm not able to change the fonts when downloading them either

Comment: Check your console it's CORS errors so you cannot link to the font files with the url but you must download them and use them locally, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work then it is probably CORS you're dealing with. Please do not use the java2s website as a reference for html and css because this site is very very old and not up-to-date.

First, the browser will try to load the modern woff2 font. If it fails then it will try to load the older woff font. The ttf font is a fallback for very old browsers/devices. At the end, if no fonts can be loaded , it falss back to the default serif font.

**edit** all fonts fail to load. Reason: they has been blocked by CORS policy.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Font Sample</title>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bitstream Vera Serif Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Bitstream Vera Serif Bold'),
         url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.woff')  format('woff'),
         url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf')   format('truetype');
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This is Bitstream Vera Serif Bold.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It changed from the default font, but not to Verana Serif Bold, but to Arial...….

Comment: The "mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd" are available but they all fail to load. Reason: they has been blocked by CORS policy. To solve this, you can download the 3 font files and save them on your domain, or use a font from https://fonts.google.com

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code into this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Font Sample</title>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bitstream Vera Serif Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(VeraSeBd.ttf)

}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
This is Bitstream Vera Serif Bold.
</body>
</html>
```

And downloaded the font, and placed it in the root directory
It seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You are welcome. With the .woff2 and .woff font files you are up-to-date. I recommend to download these files and insert them as shown in my post. The .ttf font is very old and outdated. All browsers use .woff2 fonts, except the very old internet explorer and old versions of Edge but these old browsers use the .woff font.